# Change materialized view to regular view

Tags: postgresql, sql-view, materialized-views

I have a materialized view in my database for performance reasons. The constraints of the environment have changed and now I need to make updates appear more rapidly and the performance of the view itself is less important. How can I alter the materialized view to be a regular view instead? Looking for something like:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW viewname TO VIEW
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Approach 1: Manual copy/paste method

---

As materialized view and view are different objects in your database, you'll need to delete materialized view and create the view based on your materialized view.

You can show the `SELECT` statement from your materialized view in two ways:

**Way 1:** Using directive

```
\d+ viewname
```

**Way 2:** Do an `SELECT` on internal tables

```
SELECT definition FROM pg_matviews WHERE matviewname='viewname';
```

Both commands listed above will show the `SELECT` used on your materialized view so, you can copy in an text editor to paste before.

The next step is `DROP` the materialized view and create the new simply as:

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW viewname;
```

The last step is ceate the view:

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS <paste your SELECT statement here>
```

And, voilá. Th manual way is done

### Approach 2: Automatically change from matview to view by a function

---

Another option that we can use if you can't do copy/paste is create a function to convert the data. as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id int, name varchar);
INSERT INTO mytable (1, 'John');
INSERT INTO mytable (2, 'Mary');
```

Created above the mytable as example

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mymatview1 AS SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Created a materialized view based on mytable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION frommaviewttoview(VARCHAR) 
RETURNS VOID as $$
    DECLARE
      mymatview ALIAS FOR $1; 
      tomatview VARCHAR;
    BEGIN
        SELECT definition INTO tomatview
          FROM pg_matviews
         WHERE matviewname=$1;
       EXECUTE 'DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW '||mymatview;
       EXECUTE 'CREATE VIEW '||mymatview||' AS '||tomatview;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Created a function to convert the materialized view to view

```
\d
```

And, with `\d` we can see the materialized view information as the image below shows, that extracted from my tests.

[image: View converted as example]

This function get the definition and executes `DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW` and `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` with the `SELECT` definition of the original materialized view.

So, you need to take more control if you have indexed materialized views so, if any reference blocks, your materialized view probably will not be excluded and extra controls needed to be done.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm ideally looking for a hands free way of doing this because I'm currently managing AWS/postgres/k8s/backend config/cicd/ids/edge/and remote client networks and the context switching is impossible. So I need to help myself by automating as much as possible and copy pasting as little as possible. I think I can figure out how to use what you shared to do that but do you see anything that would catch me up if I tried to do that?

Comment: @voutasaurus. I improved my answer to use in more automated way with a plpgsql function. Worked on Postgresql 11. Hope that will help you.